# Could we have community ads too?

Tags: discussion

On many of the other Stack Exchange sites I've seen meta posts collecting community ads to submit to help advertise their site across the network.

Are community ads something that we would want to do?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why we weren't asked other than, perhaps, they don't normally do it for beta sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beta sites don't get community ads.  You could try asking, but I think others have asked before us.

However, we can certainly advertise *our* site on *other* (graduated) ones that *do* have community ads, if there are any sites where we think that would be welcome.  For example, Worldbuilding, a fairly new beta site, is advertising on Physics, Sci Fi, RPG, and a few others.  If there's a site out there whose readers are likely to be particularly interested in pets, we could design an ad for our community and submit it there.  I can't think of such a site off-hand, but I haven't perused the whole list.

Comment: Here is [a fairly recent meta post supporting Monica's argument](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/community-ads-faq/237283#237283)